# Changing the language of a moment.js script from english to german

Tags: javascript, momentjs, builder

I wrote the following code, but the outcome is not in german, as it supposed to be.

I use the Browser-Application "Application Builder" by Watson Explorer Engine.

```
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"> </script>



<script>
  moment.locale("de");

  function worldClock() {
      moment.locale("de");
      var now = moment();

      $(".clock").each(function() {
          moment.locale("de");
          var timezone = $(this).data('tz');
          <%# we check the timezone to make sure it's valid %>
          if (moment.tz.zone(timezone)) {
              moment.locale("de");
              var tz_now = now.tz(timezone);
              $(this).html("<div class='date'>" + tz_now.locale("de").format('LL') + "</div>");
              $(this).append("<div class='time'>" + tz_now.format('LL') + "</div>");
              $(this).append("<div class='time'>" + tz_now.locale() + "</div>");
              $(this).append("<div class='time'>" + moment(1316116057189).locale('de').fromNow() + "</div>");
              $(this).append("<div class='timezone'>" + timezone + "</div>");
          } else {
              $(this).html("Unrecognized time zone " + timezone);
          }
      });
      setTimeout("worldClock()", 1000)
  }
  $(function() {
      worldClock();
  });    
</script>
<style>
        .clock {
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.time {
font-size:1.4em;
color:#005288;
padding: 4px 0;
}
.timezone {
font-size:1.1em;
font-weight: 500;
}
</style>
 <div class="worldclock">
  <%# Some other time zones:  America/St_Johns Antarctica/Vostok Asia/Almaty     Asia/Istanbul Asia/Novosibirsk %>
  <%# Asia/Samarkand Australia/Adelaide Australia/Adelaide Etc/GMT+9     Europe/Vilnius Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh %>
  <%# this is not an exhaustive list, you also can use Etc/GMT+n or Etc/GMT-n where n is an offset. %>
    <div data-tz="Europe/Berlin" class="clock">
    </div>
    <div data-tz="Asia/Singapore" class="clock">
    </div>

</div>
```

I treid a lot, but the outcome is always in English...
I hope, someone has any idea.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you including [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)? Your code, converted into a snippet, works as expected (it shows values in german).

Comment: First fo all, thank you for testing the code!

But even if I add these lines, the outcome is still in English:
 `<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
 <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.js"></script>`

Comment: You can simply use `moment-timezone-with-dat‌​a.js`, there is no need to import `moment-timezone.js` again. Please use CDN instead of momentjs.com, e.g. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></sc‌​ript>`

Comment: Thank you VincenzoC, but even your alternative source did not work... :/

Which type of programme or tool did you use to try out my code?

Comment: You have to import german locale, you can use `moment-with-locales.js` or `locale/de.js`. Check you have somenthing like: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/‌​0.5.14/moment-timezo‌​ne-with-data-2012-20‌​22.min.js"></sc‌​rip‌​t>` in your page.